# I am trying to identify the seal on a vase, Any help gratefully received (Characters identified: 南宋官窑)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

I am trying to identify the seal mark on a Chinese Yixing body vase. The characters are in what I believe to be seal format. I have tried using Google translate by hand writing but, the results I received do not appear to be remotely similar. Ideally I would love a translation of what it means however I would gratefully appreciate any help or guidance that can be offered please. Thank you in anticipation.

[image: Seal mark on Yixing bodied vase]

Answer (score 3):

The characters are

```
官南
窑宋
```

which translates to *State [Kiln](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiln) of the [Southern Song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Song_dynasty#Southern_Song,_1127%E2%80%931279)*.

Comment: 南宋是史書上的名稱，南宋人會自稱南宋嗎?

Comment: 也有後人命名該處所的可能吧，不一定是原來的名稱。

Comment: cf https://baike.baidu.com/item/南宋官窑/8895444